# Is it possible in Clojure to cause a deadlock (or another bad case) using agents?

Tags: concurrency, clojure, deadlock, race-condition, agent

Clojure agents are a powerful tool. Since actions to the agents are asynchronously sent using functions "send" and "send-off", in theory something like deadlock couldn't happen.

Is it possible to write some Clojure code (for example invoking from some action another action to another agent) using agents in which we have some concurrency problem - it could be deadlock, race condition or anything else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`send` and `send-off` add the functions to queues for the agent and return immediately.  Thus, due to their asynchronous nature, it is not possible for them to deadlock.

However, the worker pool used by `send` is intended for computational work and is thus a fixed pool size (2 + # of cores).  If you (incorrectly) invoke `send` with a task that can block for I/O or something else, that task will block one of the fixed number of cpu threads in the pool.  If you did that with (2 + # of cores) tasks at the same time, you could effectively block the cpu thread pool.  The solution of course is to use the correct `send-off` instead.  The worker pool used by `send-off` is unbounded.

On sending within an action, the [agents](http://clojure.org/agents) page states:

> If during the function execution any other dispatches are made
>   (directly or indirectly), they will be held until after the state of
>   the Agent has been changed.

When the dispatch occurs at the end of the agent, the send places the item in the send queue and returns immediately.  Because agents never block waiting for a resource, there is no way to create a deadlock cycle.

There is also no possibility for a **data race** - the state of an agent should be immutable Clojure data.  The agent applies the change function within a send and replaces the state of the agent atomically.  Readers (via `dereference` or `@`) see a stable value at some point in the agent's lifetime.  If you need coordination of readers and writers, you must use [refs](http://clojure.org/refs).

There is a possibility of a **race condition**: two calls to `send` from different threads can "race" to be put in the queue of an agent and also concurrent readers may perceive different (stable) values depending on when they read the agent's timeline.  However, this is the nature of asynchronous computation.  If you want coordinated computation when reading or writing multiple resources, you must use [refs](http://clojure.org/refs).

Comment: Thanks for the full answer. Unfortunately, that's all that I expected. Ofcourse these features are so cool for Clojure language, but it's bad for my PhD work :) I've tried to verify some cases of concurrent behavior in the Clojure programs.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that would be possible because the Asynchronous nature of the "send" calls are there to prevent such kind of deadlock issues. In case send was synchronous then it would have been easily possible i.e to call send again in the send function to the same agent, now send would get stuck if it was synchronous.